# How to display an object in PowerShell cmdlet whose one property itself is an complex object

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a cmdlet which outputs an user-defined object `Metric`.

`Metric` class has data-members:

1. `Count` - of type `int16`
2. `Dimension` - of type `List<MetricDimension>`

`MetricDimension` is a user-defined object with data-members:

1. `Name` - of type `String`
2. `OperatorProperty` - of type `String`
3. `Values` - of type `List<String>`

When I output my Metric object following output is shown.

```
Dimension : {Dim1,Dim2}
Count     : 2
```

What I want is that it should display the complete details of the object (`MetricDimension`) including `OperatorProperty` & `Values` list not just the `Name`.

Is it possible to display every property of dimensions object?

```cs
// Summary:
//     Specifies a metric dimension.
public class MetricDimension
{
    public MetricDimension();
    public MetricDimension(string name, string operatorProperty, IList<string> values);

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "operator")]
    public string OperatorProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "values")]
    public IList<string> Values { get; set; }

    public virtual void Validate();
}

public class Metric
{
    public Metric();
    public Metric(int16 count, MetricDimension dimension);

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "count")]
    public int16 Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dimension")]
    public IList<MetricDimension> Dimension{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In fact, all properties of the object *are* displayed. `Dimensions` is a list. So what you mean is not "all properties" but "all elements" of the list.

Comment: @marsze Yes, I want to display all element of the list Dimension. Is it possible?

Comment: `(your-command).Dimension`

Comment: The question back here is: in what format do you want display the complex object? If this is **PowerShell**, you might want to look into the [`ConvertTo-Expression` cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard output will rarely drill-down into your deep object graph to display pleasingly. You could convert to JSON to see it all:

```
do_your_thing | ConvertTo-Json
```

Beware of circular references. You can limit the depth that it descends to with the `-Depth` parameter.